# The web server built-in Azure app service

Tags: azure, web, webserver

Background:

I am hosting a static web app, generated by NUXTJS on an Azure App Service.
Now I want to configure something more by the `web.config` like set CORS setting for multiple domains.
But I cannot find any document to figure out what kind of web server has been integrated/installed within the azure app service.

Questions:

1. Maybe an `IIS` if the platform is Window based, otherwise `Apache` when creating AAS in Linux based. Is it correct?
2. And what is the corresponding version for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different HTTP server approaches in App Service for Windows and App Service for Linux.

**Azure App Service for Windows** runs on IIS with the use of modules.

- .NET Core apps in App Service on Windows are hosted by ASP.NET Core module

[image]

- Node.js apps in App Service on Windows are hosted with [IISNode](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode).
  The IISNode project provides a native IIS 7/8 module that allows hosting of node.js applications in IIS 7/8 and IIS 7/8 Express.
- Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 is by default is installed on App Service in root folders on the server
- Java apps in App Service on Windows are hosted with [Maven plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-webapp-maven-plugin)

**Azure App Service for Linux** works a bit differently.
[image]
https://anthonychu.ca/post/jekyll-azure-app-service-linux/

App Service for Linux comes with a bunch of preconfigured containers such as Node, PHP, Java, Python, Ruby and .NET Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-language-stack-settings