# Accessing On-Premises database from Azure App Service Linux Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure, docker, azure-appservice

We have previously used Azure App Service on Linux operating system paired with a hybrid connection to a local Sql server and it all works fine as expected. Now we have migrated to Azure App Service in Linux operating system Docker container with hybrid connection to local Sql server and now we cannot connect to our Sql database, error appears:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/API.dll"]
```

Is it possible to establish a connection to a local database from a Docker Container App Service, or what could be wrong?

Comment: Both App Service Linux and App Service Linux Docker container are running your code in Docker.
I assume your new App Service Linux Docker does not have hybrid connection configured.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67718442/the-web-server-built-in-azure-app-service/67721199#67721199

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I described in the question, we have set up a hybrid connection the same way as for App Service, maybe you know that we can also check to get rid of this Sql error?

Comment: Did you try to connect to App Service Linux Docker container via SSH using Kudu and test connectivity using telnet on SQL Server port?

Comment: No I did what you suggested and I get the following output:

root@11ce1edcc40f:~# telnet <MY_DNS> 1433
Trying 127.0.0.14...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Try to use command tcpping <Endpoint host> 1433
Is the status of your Hybrid Connection connected?
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-app-services-with-hybrid-connections/

Comment: Please check logs bellow:
tcpping <Endpoint host> 1433
seq 0: tcp response from 127.0.0.15 [closed]  0.073 ms
seq 1: tcp response from 127.0.0.15 [closed]  0.074 ms
seq 2: tcp response from 127.0.0.15 [closed]  0.071 ms
seq 3: tcp response from 127.0.0.15 [closed]  0.089 ms
seq 4: tcp response from 127.0.0.15 [closed]  0.081 ms
seq 5: tcp response from 127.0.0.15 [closed]  0.074 ms